How to convert ESLint for TypeScript from .eslintrc to flat config?
I need to migrate the legacy ESLint configuration to new flat config version for React JS & TS project. There are problems when I attempt to convert first override for .ts, .tsx.
.eslintrc
{
  {/*common config*/}
  "overrides": [
    {
      // here the main problem
      "files": ["**/*.{ts,tsx}"],
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
      "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
          "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2020,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "project": ["./tsconfig.json", "./e2e/tsconfig.json"]
      },
      "globals": {
        "React": true,
        "JSX": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
        "plugin:react/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "react/require-default-props": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}


So, this is what I came up with:
eslint.config.mjs:
export default [
{
  {/*common config*/},
  //converted to this
  ...tseslint.config(
    eslint.configs.recommended,
    ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
    ...tseslint.configs.recommendedTypeChecked,
    {
      ignores: ['**/*.{js,jsx}', 'config/*.js', "./deploy.js"],
      languageOptions: {
        parserOptions: {
          project: ['./tsconfig.json'],
          tsconfigRootDir: import.meta.dirname,
        },
      },
      rules: {
        "no-use-before-define": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": ["error"],
        "react/require-default-props": "off"
      }
    }
  )
]

However, I face this error:
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 9.3.0

Error: Error while loading rule '@typescript-eslint/await-thenable': You have used a rule which requires parserServices to be generated. You must therefore provide a value for the "parserOptions.project" property for @typescript-eslint/parser.
Parser: undefined
Note: detected a parser other than @typescript-eslint/parser. Make sure the parser is configured to forward "parserOptions.project" to @typescript-eslint/parser.


Please cut it down to a [mre].
